# Testing app on my own iPhone - which provisioning file do I want?

Tags: ios, xcode

I followed a tutorial online that had me create a new app id for my app I want to test on my iPhone, but should I be linking it to that one, or the iOS Team Provisioning Profile that Apple links to by default (and with the automatic setup it links it to that)?

I'm confused which one I should be linking it to under Build Settings, basically. The custom one, or the seemingly general one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use In-App Purchases, Game Center or Push Notifications in your app you can use the Team Provisioning Profile.

If your app uses one of these features you have to use an explicit app id for this app, and to use this explicit app id you will need a separate provisioning profile.
The Team Profile uses a wildcard app id and will work with all your other apps.

If you have already created a provisioning profile for your particular app you can of course use this one too.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install provision profile first after that add provision profile in your app. set build settings according to that provision profile.

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking.